# Does bootstrap data-toggle="collapse" get affected by https vs http?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, http, drop-down-menu, https

I have been working on a website for a while which uses Bootstrap collapse value to list related topics. Clicking on a link will show a drawer of related topics. See code block for reference:

```html
<li><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#accountingcost" name="a">Accounting cost</a>
  <div id="accountingcost" class="collapse">
    <ul>
      <li>D. Theory of the Firm
        <ul>
          <li>D2. Cost Functions
          ...
</li>
```

It was working fine for a while on an URL starting with http://. However, after some changes were made and I've transitioned to https://, this particular part of the site stopped working. Clicking on the link didn't expand the drawers but yielded https://siteaddresshere.html#accountingcost in the address bar and no other action.

I was wondering if anyone knew how http or https affected the how data-toggle works and if there's a fix for it?

Thank you!

Comment: No errors in console?

Comment: No errors, so I'm not sure what's happened.

Comment: You seem to care about the anonymity of your domain more than you care about our ability to discover the cause of the problem. It's insulting. You're asking for help but block us from inspecting. Fine. I have a good guess at why it's not working. Not going to share until you create a [mcve]. Your current snippet is not working because of invalid markup and that's (most likely) not why it's not working on your live website.